# iOS: UIButton titleLabel -- does it do anything at all?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uilabel, uifont

I want to make a UIButton with type UIButtonTypeCustom (for the shape).  I want to assign the title using button.titleLabel because I need to specify the font.  The following code looks like it should work, but doesn't -- no label shows up, period.

```
UIImage *editButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"editButton.png"];
float width = editButtonImage.size.width;
float height = editButtonImage.size.height;

UIButton *editButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
editButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
[editButton setBackgroundImage: editButtonImage forState: UIControlStateNormal];
editButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
editButton.titleLabel.text = @"Edit";
editButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
editButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
editButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica" size: 14];
[self.view addSubview: editButton];
```

Everyone always says to use setTitle:forState: but that gives you a font I don't like.  The titleLabel method is NOT deprecated -- it should work.

I have run into this several times before and always just worked around it, but I'd really like to figure it out.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Setting the `titleLabel`'s `text` property like that has no effect. Instead, call `-setTitle:forState:` on the button:

```
[editButton setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```

The reason for this is because the button can have different titles for different states (e.g., `UIControlStateDisabled`, `UIControlStateHighlighted`). Setting a property for the `UIControlStateNormal` control state will apply to all the states if you don't specify the others explicitly.

Per the documentation for `UIButton`:

> This class provides methods for setting the title, image, and other appearance properties of a button. By using these accessors, you can specify a different appearance for each button state.

You can customize label's color and shadow color based on the state. See `-setTitleColor:forState` and `-setTitleShadowColor:forState`, respectively. The rest of the properties on `titleLabel`, such as `textAlignment` and `font`, should work as you have them set now and should apply to all the control states.

Specifically, see the documentation for `UIButton`'s `titleLabel` property: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623992-titlelabel

`titleLabel` itself is read-only, but that doesn't mean you can't change the values of its own properties, such as font, line break mode, etc.

Comment: So the ONE thing you can't set using titleLabel is the actual text value.  That seems a bit strange to me, but okay.

Comment: It is a bit counterintuitive at first. Seemingly, setting the label's `text` property would just be a shortcut for calling `-setTitle:forState`, but it isn't.

Comment: Similarly it looks like you can't set the textColor property of titleLabel directly, but have to use the setTitleColor:forState: method. Thanks for mentioning this, because it's not in the documentation.

Comment: `titleLabel.textAlignment` is incorrect. To align the text you must use `titleLabel.contentHorizontalAlignment = .Left`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I worked it out using Swift 4.2.

```
counterButton.setTitle("Start Counter",
                      for:UIControl.State.normal)
```