# Set Buttons TitleLabel Text

Tags: uibutton, storyboard, label

Hi all I defined a UIButton on header file and afterwards I linked it to a button in storyboard

I wrote this code in ViewDidload

```
[super viewDidLoad];
firstButton.titleLabel.text = @"Hello Osman";
```

and buttons label didnt change why ?

Sıncerely

Comment: Can you provide more details?.. What do you see?

Comment: Its name is "button" (default I didnt change it ) and when that page is opened I see "button" not "Hello Osman" on that Button

Comment: You said your connection was correct in the IB right?
Try this : [firstButton setTitle: @"Hello Osman" forState: UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: Storyboard I jut Put the mouse on button name and muse pressed and put it on Button :D How can I explain more :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS: UIButton titleLabel -- does it do anything at all?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910446/ios-uibutton-titlelabel-does-it-do-anything-at-all)

Comment: problem solved I forget to write synthesize :D

Answer (score 1):

Ok I tried what you have described in your question.

```
firstButton.titleLabel.text = @"Hello Osman"; // This doesn't work 
[firstButton setTitle: @"Hello Osman" forState: UIControlStateNormal]; // This works
```