# Change UIButton's title via titleLabel.text property does not work: why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I know this question must be answered before but still I'd like to know why first line of code couldn't change title of the `UIButton` while the second can. Besides first line is copied from a Objective-C book of BigNerdRanch...which I take as sample that works.

```
self.assetTypeButton.titleLabel.text=@"foo"; //doesn't work

[self.assetTypeButton setTitle:@"foo" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //this works and button title is changed.
```

Comment: [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11417134/1066828) & [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4910521/1066828)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS: UIButton titleLabel -- does it do anything at all?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910446/ios-uibutton-titlelabel-does-it-do-anything-at-all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better explanation from [Apple TitleLabel](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/titleLabel) [and setTitle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitle:forState:)

**titleLabel**

```
UIButton *button  = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeSystem];
button.titleLabel.font            = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 12];
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode   = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

> Do not use the label object to set the text color or the shadow color.
>   Instead, use the setTitleColor:forState: and
>   setTitleShadowColor:forState: methods of this class to make those
>   changes.
>
> **The titleLabel property returns a value even if the button has not**
>   **been displayed yet. The value of the property is nil for system
>   buttons.**

**setTitle**

> Use this method to set the title for the button. The title you
>   specify derives its formatting from the button’s associated label
>   object. If you set both a title and an attributed title for the
>   button, the button prefers the use of the attributed title over this
>   one.
>
> At a minimum, you should set the value for the normal state. If a
>   title is not specified for a state, the default behavior is to use the
>   title associated with the UIControlStateNormal state. If the value for
>   UIControlStateNormal is not set, then the property defaults to a
>   system value.